# How do I create a manifest file to point my executable/plugin to my specific version of a Qt.dll?

Tags: windows, qt, deployment, dll, manifest

I'm having trouble understanding how manifests work/what they are intended for.

My situation is this:  I need to deploy my own stand alone .exe that implements Qt as well as a plugin (.8bf, photoshop plugin, .dll in disguise) that implements Qt.

I have my own Qt DLL's that I've compiled with a custom namespace and infix name that I want to install into C:\Program Files\MyCompany\Qt

Can I use manifests to have both my .exe and plugin 'point' at these Qt DLLs?  Both the exe and plugin are located in different subdirs of C:\Program Files\MyCompany and a shell link to the plugin is installed in the photoshop\plug-ins dir.

Are manifests what I'm looking for and if so, what steps are needed to accomplish this?  It seems like the Qt DLLs will need some manifests to identify/register themselves but after going on a circular goose chase on msdn links I decided to ask here (after searching and only finding partially related questions of course).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like making your assembly available to the assembly cache would solve your problem - and it's the problem that the GAC was designed to solve - but it's overkill.

Just ship the same version of these DLL's in both directories.

---

Manifests are used to ensure that your program uses a specific version of a DLL (or a set of DLLs).

The best known example is when your application tries to load `comctl32.dll`.

This dll is normally found in your **system32**:

```
 Directory of C:\Windows\System32

11/20/2010  09:25 ᴀᴍ           633,856 comctl32.dll
               1 File(s)        633,856 bytes
```

And unless you did anything special you would get this version of the dll (version 5.82). But it's common for programs to **not** want this version of `comctl32`. Most programs written for Windows XP or newer want to be sure they load **version 6** of `comctl32`. They do this by specifying an entry in their executable's assembly manifest saying they want a *particular* version of the common controls library:

```
<dependency>
   <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity 
               type="win32" 
               name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls" 
               version="6.0.0.0" 
               processorArchitecture="X86" 
               publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df" 
               language="*">
      </assemblyIdentity>
   </dependentAssembly>
</dependency>
```

Now if the application tries to load `comctl32.dll`, even though there is a version already in its search path (or even in the same folder), Windows will *instead* give it **Version 6** of `comctl32.dll`. This dll is tucked away in special location, where people are not supposed to touch:

```
 Directory of C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7600.16385_none_421189da2b7fabfc

07/13/2009  09:03 ᴩᴍ         1,680,896 comctl32.dll
               1 File(s)      1,680,896 bytes
```

> **Bonus chatter**: The reason `WinSxS` is so large is because it contains every version of every dll that someone might want. i count 3,619 assemblies in there. The reason you don't want to delete WinSxS is that a program wants one of those dlls.

It sounds like the solution you'd like is to create an Assembly Manifest for `Qt` (which defines a series of related dlls), and then register *that* assembly with the Windows side-by-side system.

Unfortunately, it seems that in order to be placed in WinSxS, the assembly files must be digitally signed. It *also* seems as though only through Windows Installer can assemblies by installed in the Side-by-Side cache:

> You should install shared side-by-side assemblies as components of a Windows Installer package. This can be the same installation package used to install or update your application. If the shared assembly is shipped as part of multiple applications, you should provide a merge module that can be incorporated into these applications' installation packages and create a catalog for the files in the assembly.
>
> Windows Installer version 2.0 or later is required to install assemblies. For more information, see the [Windows Installer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc185688%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) SDK and the sections under [Installation of Win32 Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369292%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

## See also

- [Installing Side-by-side Assemblies as Shared Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375188%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Private Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375674%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I am now a firm believer in the 'just ship the damn dlls' paradigm.  Thanks!

Comment: @Tom: It would be great if Qt themselves created/signed/shipped-as-merge-modules the various versions people might depend on.